# Union of Finitely Generated Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

In general the union of chain of ideals of a ring is an ideal. But I did not get the following idea.

> Let $I$ be an ideal of an integral domain $R$ and let $J = \bigcup_{A\subseteq I} (A^{-1})^{-1},$ where $A$ is a finitely generated ideal of $R$ contained in $I$, $A^{-1} = \langle{x: x \in K, xA \subseteq R}\rangle $ and $K$ is the quotient field of $R$. Then $J$ is an ideal of $R$.

This appear in closure operation of set of ideals. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every finite subset of $I$ is contained in a finitely generated ideal of $R$ which is contained in $I$, so that union is just $I$, no?

Comment: Sorry I just correct the question.

Comment: Isn't this trivial? At least show us that if $r\in R$ and $x\in J$ then $rx\in J$.

Comment: Thank you user 26857. It seems the addition is not obvious.

Comment: Well, for addition chose the sum of the two finitely generated ideals.